# Selecting the 'next' row given specific criteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this set of data and need to base my queries on what is in the 'next' logical row.

```
 id |  area |  order
 1     front   1
 2     back    2
 3     left    3
 4     middle  4
 5     right   5
```

I had a query such as this to count the number of instances where a front area was followed by back area

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) 
     FROM table AS t2 
     WHERE t2.area = 'back' AND t2.order = (t1.order +1)) AS c,  
FROM table AS t1
WHERE t1.area = 'front'
```

But, the data set has now changed and could look something like this

```
 id |  area |  order
 1     front   1
 2     back    3
 4     left    4
 6     middle  7
 9     right   9
```

Now the IDs and order are not incrementing, some data has been removed and then re-added.

How can I write the same query again given this new data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query is rather clever.  Here is a slightly different approach.  It gets the next area in a subquery (using a correlated subquery as in your example).  It then counts the rows where the conditions are true:

```
select sum(case when area = 'Front' and nextarea = 'Back' then 1 else 0 end)
from (SELECT t1.*,
             (SELECT t2.area 
              FROM table t2 
              where t2.order > t1.order
              order by t2.order
              limit 1
             ) as nextarea 
FROM table t1;
```

This query is more expensive that yours.  You were able to use a nice equality condition on the `order` column.  Here, a sort is needed with the `limit` to get the next value.  A composite index on `(order, area)` should help performance.

Comment: Thanks @GordanLinoff - I really Rubber Ducked this one (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Saw the answer right away. Nice to have the way I did it originally seconded though!

Comment: @jakenoble . . . I hadn't heard that term before.  Excellent, and I've experienced it often.

Comment: Any ideas @GordonLinoff? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099683/improving-this-mysql-query-select-as-sub-query - my approach seems to have come unstuck.