# Improving this MySQL Query - Select as sub-query

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-optimization

I have this query

```
  SELECT  
   shot.hole AS hole,
   shot.id AS id,
   (SELECT s.id FROM shot AS s 
      WHERE s.hole = shot.hole AND s.shot_number > shot.shot_number AND shot.round_id = s.round_id 
       ORDER BY s.shot_number ASC LIMIT 1) AS next_shot_id,
   shot.distance AS distance_remaining,
   shot.type AS hit_type,
   shot.area AS onto
  FROM shot 
  JOIN course ON shot.course_id = course.id
  JOIN round ON shot.round_id = round.id
  WHERE round.uID = 78
```

This returns 900~ rows in around 0.7 seconds. This is OK-ish, but there are more lines like this required

```
(SELECT s.id FROM shot AS s 
 WHERE s.hole = shot.hole AND s.shot_number > shot.shot_number AND shot.round_id = s.round_id 
 ORDER BY s.shot_number ASC LIMIT 1) AS next_shot_id,
```

For example

```
   (SELECT s.id FROM shot AS s 
    WHERE s.hole = shot.hole AND s.shot_number < shot.shot_number AND shot.round_id = s.round_id 
    ORDER BY s.shot_number ASC LIMIT 1) AS past_shot_id,
```

Adding this increases the load time to 10s of seconds which is far too long and the page often doesn't load at all or MySQL just locks up and using `show processlist` shows that the query is just sat there `sending data`.

Removing the `ORDER BY s.shot_number ASC` clause in those sub queries reduces the query time down to 0.05 seconds which is much much better. But the `ORDER BY` is required to ensure that the next or past row (shot) is returned, rather than any old random row.

How can I improve this query to make it run faster and return the same results. Perhaps [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870446/selecting-the-next-row-given-specific-criteria-in-mysql) for obtaining the next and past rows is sub optimal and I need to look at a different way of returning those next and previous row IDs?

**EDIT - additional background info**

The query was fine on my testing domain, a subdomain. But when moved to the live domain the issues started. Hardly anything was changed yet the whole site came to halt because of these new slow queries. Key notes:

- Different domain
- Different folder in /var/www
- Same DB
- Same DB credentials
- Same code
- Added indexes in an attempt to fix - this didn't help

Could any of these affected the load time?

Comment: Can you figure out how to rewrite your correlated subquery as an uncorrelated one? Or omit the subquery altogether>

Comment: @JakeNoble . . . Are the shots assigned incrementally?  Are there any gaps?

Comment: That should be possible @Strawberry - should that improve speed?

Comment: @GordonLinoff there are gaps, shots might go 1,2,4,6,8

Comment: :-) @jakenoble If I did not think it would, I would not have suggested it. That said, I've been wrong before...

Comment: @Strawberry I have looked again and I don't think I can make it uncorrelated. Because I need the original round_id from the main query in order to get the correct shot in the correct round in the sub query.

Comment: In which case, you JOIN the subquery ON that condition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Strawberry's answer, doing additional left-join for a "pre-query" to get all the prior / next IDs, then join out to get whatever details you need.

```
select
      Shot.ID,
      Shot.Hole,
      Shot.Distance as Distance_Remaining,
      Shot.Type as Hit_Type,
      Shot.Area as Onto
      PriorShot.Hole as PriorHole,
      PriorShot.Distance as PriorDistanceRemain,
      NextShot.Hole as NextHole,
      NextShot.Distance as NextDistanceRemain
   from
      ( SELECT 
              shot.id, 
              MIN(nextshot.id) as NextShotID,
              MAX(priorshot.id) as PriorShotID
           FROM 
              round 
                 JOIN shot 
                    on round.id = shot.round_id
                    LEFT JOIN shot nextshot
                       ON shot.round_id = nextshot.round_id
                       AND shot.hole = nextshot.hole
                       AND shot.shot_number < nextshot.shot_number
                    LEFT JOIN shot priorshot
                       ON shot.round_id = priorshot.round_id
                       AND shot.hole = priorshot.hole
                       AND shot.shot_number > priorshot.shot_number
           WHERE
              round.uID = 78
           GROUP BY 
              shot.id ) AllShots
         JOIN Shot
            on AllShots.id = Shot.ID
            LEFT JOIN shot PriorShot
               on AllShots.PriorShotID = PriorShot.ID
            LEFT JOIN shot NextShot
               on AllShots.NextShotID = NextShot.ID
```

The inner query gets only those for round.uID = 78, then you can join to the next / prior as needed.  I did not add the joins to the course and round tables as no result columns were presented, but could easily be added.

Comment: this executes with my data in 0.2 seconds which i quicker, but not blisteringly fast. The results from these queries are cached but there are several of these on a page so the initial load time maybe significant with a load time of 0.2 second each - still its better than my soluton

Comment: I have implemented this now, bit of a task as there was a lot of stuff to re write. But it works much faster now thanks @DRapp

Comment: @jakenoble, if you had a bunch of "uID" users you were interested in, you would minimally have to change the WHERE clause to " IN (78, blah, blah)", and the field list and group by to include whoever the other "users" you wanted to present.  Also, the LEFT-JOINs to include the respective user for the shots.

Answer (score 2):

This will get marked down in a minute for 'not being an answer', but it illustrates a possible solution without simply handing it to you on a plate....

```
 SELECT * FROM ints;
 +---+
 | i |
 +---+
 | 0 |
 | 1 |
 | 2 |
 | 3 |
 | 4 |
 | 5 |
 | 6 |
 | 7 |
 | 8 |
 | 9 |
 +---+

 SELECT x.i, MIN(y.i) FROM ints x LEFT JOIN ints y ON y.i > x.i GROUP BY x.i;
 +---+----------+
 | i | MIN(y.i) |
 +---+----------+
 | 0 |        1 |
 | 1 |        2 |
 | 2 |        3 |
 | 3 |        4 |
 | 4 |        5 |
 | 5 |        6 |
 | 6 |        7 |
 | 7 |        8 |
 | 8 |        9 |
 | 9 |     NULL |
 +---+----------+
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this approach. Use a JOIN rather than another sub query select. Will this work if ints has numbers missing?

Comment: Yes. It only considers whether one number is larger than another number - not how much larger!

Comment: I too like this option, and if you left-join again for the MAX() to get the prior shot, they will have all 3 key IDs (prior, current, next) and can join to the shot table for the details to compare against in either direction...

Comment: @Strawberry I used DRapp's solution which was heavily based on your idea - thanks for your input +1

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how well the following performs.  It replaces the joining operations with string operations.

```
  SELECT shot.hole AS hole, shot.id AS id,
         substring_index(substring_index(shots, ',', find_in_set(shot.id, ss.shots) + 1), ',', -1
                        ) as nextsi,
         substring_index(substring_index(shots, ',', find_in_set(shot.id, ss.shots) - 1), ',', -1
                        ) as prevsi,
         shot.distance AS distance_remaining, shot.type AS hit_type, shot.area AS onto
  FROM shot JOIN
       course
       ON shot.course_id = course.id JOIN
       round
       ON shot.round_id = round.id join
       (select s.round_id, s.hole, group_concat(s.id order by s.shot_number) as shots
        from shot s
        group by s.round_id, s.hole
       ) ss
       on ss.round_id = shot.round_id and ss.hole = shot.hole
  WHERE round.uID = 78
```

Note that this doesn't work fully -- it will produce erroneous results on the first and last shot.  I'm wondering how the performance is before fixing those details.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with MySQL's substring_index but that codes gives me `Error in query (1582): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'substring_index'`

Comment: @jakenoble . . . That was because I left outer the second argument to the function.

Comment: I don't think you're defining `s`? `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 's.round_id' in 'field list'`